# MySQL - Select only last record of each foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that go like this (stripped version):

```
Create table A (
    AID Int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AID)
)

Create table B (
    BID Int NOT NULL,
    AID Int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES A(AID)
)

Create table C (
    CID Int NOT NULL,
    BID Int NOT NULL,
    Price Decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CID),
    FOREIGN KEY (BID) REFERENCES B(BID)
)
```

Each record in A can only have one up-to-date record in B (last ID is considered as latest) for example: we have a record in A that has 3 associated records in B, but only the last record is considered to be up-to-date and only that one should be used.

Each time a record in B is updated (in this case inserted), all records in C are duplicated and point to the newly created record in B.

How could I get the SUM of C.Price of all A records.

So far I got: (but distinct doesn't seem to work)

```
SELECT SUM(Price)
FROM C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t2.AID, t2.BID
    FROM (
        SELECT BID, AID
        FROM B
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT AID
            FROM A
            -- some other statements go here
        ) t1
        ON t1.AID = AID
        ORDER BY BID DESC
    ) t2
) t3
ON t3.BID = C.BID
```

I hope I explained well enough. :/

Comment: What is the relation to data in table C? You explained how B is correlated, but please explain how C relates to both.

Comment: Sure, I've added more information on C.

Comment: You can provide test data and the expected result on that data?

Comment: @wchiquito I second that.  Please provide some sample data.  Perhaps make an sql fiddle with your schema and some sample data inserts we can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
select b.aid, sum(c.price)
from b join
     c
     on c.bid = b.bid
where b.bid = (select max(b2.bid) from b b2 where b2.aid = b.aid)
group by b.aid;
```

The `join` brings the tables together.  Note that `a` is not necessary -- unless you want rows from `a` that have no corresponding row in `b` (in which case, `a` would go first with a `left join`).

The `where` clause chooses the most recent `b` record for each `aid`.  The `group by` is used to get the sum.

Comment: What if the newest record of `b2.bid` is not the highest?  What if the bid changed to a lower amount?  Your max would always grab the highest number, not necessarily the most recent.

Comment: I think the OP needs a `CREATE_DATE` field in each table, then you could add an `ORDER BY CREATE DATE DESC` clause in your `WHERE` sub select

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I was after, thank you @Gordon!

Comment: You left table A out of it completely, what if an ID was removed from table A, and you have orphan data in B and C?

Comment: I added the table A in my real query. :)

Comment: @DaveKelly . . . I mention that in the paragraph after the query.  If `a` is in the query, it should either be added with a `left join` or (at least) additional columns should be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Each time a record in B is updated (in this case inserted), all
>   records in C are duplicated and point to the newly created record in
>   B.

This means that there is only record in C having the latest `BID` value. Which means, you don't need to `SUM` them, you only need to fetch the latest record.

Just to illustrate with sample data :

Table A :

```
AID
 1
 2
 3
```

Table B :

```
BID AID
 1   1
 2   1
 3   1
 4   2
 5   2
 6   2
 7   3
 8   3
 9   3
```

Table C :

```
CID BID Price
 1   1   12
 2   2   12
 3   3   20
 4   4   2
 5   5   1
 6   6   12
 7   7   22
 8   8   21
 9   9   23
```

You can use this :

```
SELECT  ab.AID,
        c.Price
 FROM (SELECT       a.aid, MAX(b.BID) AS maxB
       FROM         a a
       INNER JOIN   b b ON a.AID = b.AID
       GROUP BY     a.AID
      ) ab
INNER JOIN C c ON ab.maxB = c.BID
```

**Observe that there is no sum here.**

This will give you the result :

```
AID PRICE
 1   20
 2   12
 3   23
```

You can see this here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4943cd/3

Gordon's answer would also give you the same result -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4943cd/2

You can see that irrespective of whether `SUM` is used or not, the result is the same.

**NOTE : However, Gordon's answer (which is the marked answer here) is incorrect since it doesn't take into account the fact that if any values are removed from table A, then your result set would have redundant values.**

You can observe this if you slightly change the original data set as below :

Table A :

```
AID
 1
```

Table B :

```
BID AID
 1   1
 2   1
 3   1
 4   2
 5   2
 6   2
 7   3
 8   3
 9   3
```

Table C :

```
CID BID Price
 1   1   12
 2   2   12
 3   3   20
 4   4   2
 5   5   1
 6   6   12
 7   7   22
 8   8   21
 9   9   23
```

Gordon's query would yield you the result :

```
AID PRICE
 1   20
 2   12
 3   23
```

which is incorrect as there are no AID values 2 and 3 anymore.

**You need to join on table A to fetch *currently existing* values of AID in table A.**

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I think you are missing the point that table C could have multiple matches to the most recent record for A.

Comment: @GordonLinoff NO, you seem to have got it wrong. Table C cannot have multiple matches for most recent record in A. Why? Read the question above : `Each record in A can only have one up-to-date record in B (last ID is considered as latest)` and then `Each time a record in B is updated (in this case inserted), all records in C are duplicated and point to the newly created record in B`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you understand it correctly, at any given time, A will have only one up-to-date record in B which if updated (update word is used colloquially, the OP actually means inserted) will create a new record in C (pointing to the new B record). This means that A only has 1:1 relationship with B (in terms of applicable records) and similarly, B has 1:1 relationship with C (since whenever a new record in B is created a corresponding record in C is created). If you put 2&2 together, A and C have a 1:1 relationship too which is why C has only one match to the most recent record in A

Comment: This is exactly what i need! An outstanding answer, and using INNER JOIN is a plus. Thanks a lot! :)